# Accessing GPU Memory from Operating System Kernel

Tags: windows, kernel, gpu

We are working on a research prototype where we intend to use the GPU memory for a "GPU RAM Disk". At the moment we have a user-mode module that uses OpenCL to copy data to and from the GPU memory.

We would prefer a way of accessing the GPU memory directly from the Windows Kernel (thereby reducing the overhead introduced f.e. by the context switch). What is the best way to achieve this?

Comment: As far as I know, there is no kernel mode interface to the GPU, but you can easily allocate memory in user mode, pass the reference into kernel mode, and use the memory there. But why would you do such a thing? A RAM Disk makes no sense, and a RAM disk on GPU memory makes even less sense.

Comment: @Christopher: The GPU driver runs in kernel mode, and it controls all transfers to and from the GPU.  The user-mode APIs, such as OpenGL and DirectX, talk to device instances exposed by the kernel driver.  Other drivers can talk to those device instances equally well.  But they are vendor-specific.

Comment: @BenVoigt Of course, this is about a kernel driver to kernel driver interface. And as far as I know, there is no documented one.

Answer (score 0):

The feature you are looking for is called **zero copy memory**. Recent GPUs from both AMD and NVIDIA support it. I am not personally familiar with NVIDIA's zero copy support in OpenCL (I know it is well supported in CUDA). AMD's zero copy support is well documented in their OpenCL programming guide: http://developer.amd.com/sdks/AMDAPPSDK/assets/AMD_Accelerated_Parallel_Processing_OpenCL_Programming_Guide.pdf

See Table 4.2(OpenCL Memory Object Properties) specifically for a description of what flags to pass to `clCreateBuffer`. Most likely you will want to use `CL_MEM_USE_PERSISTENT_MEM_AMD`, which allocates memory in device (GPU) memory that is accessible from the host.